# Fail to add my own repository

Tags: application-development, ppa

I try to upload to [my PPA](https://launchpad.net/~unixinfo/+archive/ubuntu/openshell) and add it but I get this error

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unixinfo/openshell
 The OpenShell (opsh) command-line interface
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~unixinfo/+archive/ubuntu/openshell
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

Error: signing key fingerprint does not exist
Failed to add key.
```

Do you know what can be done about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/266806:

> Launchpad won't generate a signing key for your PPA until you've
>   uploaded a source package to it. Many users create PPAs without ever
>   uploading anything, so we avoid cluttering the keyservers until we
>   know the key will actually be used.

Looking at the build details for your PPA at https://launchpad.net/~unixinfo/+archive/ubuntu/openshell/+builds?build_text=&build_state=all, I noticed that none of your builds succeeded.  Therefore, there is no signing key for your PPA because I suspect that you need at least 1 successful build.

P.S.: I am assuming that "uploading a source package" means successfully building your package. If this is wrong, please let me know. In any case, having no successful builds also makes the PPA fairly pointless :).

Comment: I might have missed to add dependencies somewhere and therefore it doesn't build.

Comment: @DjDac The build log also says "gpgv: Signature made Sun Aug  6 08:00:34 2017 UTC using RSA key ID AE548961" and "gpgv: Can't check signature: public key not found", which is curious because I can certainly see your public key on Ubuntu's keyserver at http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/pks/lookup?fingerprint=on&op=index&search=0x488BDB5FFA444741D80B3CC56654F649AE548961.